# How to get two variables list from two different neural networks

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

Usually, if we define a function through a neural network in a class, then in another class, if we need the function's parameter or variables list, in tensorflow, we can use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="function name")`, it is convenient and familiar to me, although I guess there are many other more efficient ways to do so.

However, in some cases, we may need to define a function which is built upon two different neural networks, say `F(x) = F(NN_1(x), NN_2(x))`, then in another class, what is the right way to get the two variables list of both `NN_1()` and `NN_2()`? It's clear that use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="function name` here leads to get mixed variables list of `F(x)` insetead of two variables lists of `NN_1` and `NN_2`.

```
def function()
    with tf.name_scope(function):
        with tf.name_scope(subfunction_1):
           neural_network_1
        with tf.name_scope(subfunction_2):
           neural_network_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a tree of name scopes you can access the individual scope variables with:

```
vars_1 = tf.get_collection(
    tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="function_name/subfunction_name_1")
vars_2 = tf.get_collection(
    tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="function_name/subfunction_name_2")
```